# displaying a line of text - try/except

Tags: python, for-loop, exception, input, except

I want to enter such a code so that it displays the content of the line indicated by the user (as a number read from the keyboard). I need to handle an exception when the list's range (number of lines) is exceeded, however I have no idea how to put an exception here (instead "if" ).

I have written such code so far:

```
import linecache
number = int(input("Line: "))
lines = linecache.getline("text.txt", number)
print(lines)
if lines == '':
    print("no such line was found")
```

the program correctly reads the contents of the line, but when I want to handle the exception, select a line outside the text.txt range, e.g. line 250 which does not exist, it does not display the exception "no such line was found", how can i improve it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: getline doesnt return an exception so there is nothing to try to catch here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation this function does not raise an exception,
it indeed returns an empty line if the line number is not found:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline

If you want to raise an exception, then simply replace `print` with `raise ValueError` exception.

```
import linecache


number = int(input("Line: "))
line = linecache.getline("text.txt", number)


if line == '':
    raise ValueError(f"Line number {number} was not found")
```